# Prevent app language change after locale changes

Tags: android

My app supports 3 languages and the user can choose between these options.
When I change the device locale to one of my supported languages, the UI language automatically changes, the problem is that I don't want it to change if the user already choose one of my 3 supported languages within the app.

How can I prevent this automatic language change?

Comment: You shouldn't.  Use the phone's locale, there's no good reason to override it.

Comment: yes, there is. The user might want a language learning app in the language that the user is learning, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Save locale to SharedPreference when user select it in app. And add in your code default Supported Locale.

```
String userLocale = App.getSharedPreferences().getString(SELECTED_LOCALE,"your_default_string");
```

In you Application.class onCreate method add this block:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(userLocale) // 
Resources resources = getResources();
Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
configuration.setLocale(locale);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have that, what I meant is a scenario where my locale is set, and then the user minimize my app and changes the device locale and resumes my application

Comment: @Sharas add this to onConfigurationChanged() in your activity

Answer (score 0):

What I did is update a flag on my preferences to indicate if the user changed the language and check its value on Activity's `onResume()` to restart it if it did.

On Activity's `onCreate()` I update the language to the stored preference.